# Path.getComponent() in zk getting null

Tags: spreadsheet, zk, zul

hi i m trying to open a blankspreadsheet when i select and click on "new button". below is my code

jsp

```
<div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar"
        data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuBarItem" id="project">
            <span>Project</span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu" id="projectMenu">

            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem"
                      data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon   appCreateSharedPrj', onClick:function() {newspreadsheet()}">new</div>
            </div>
            </div>`

    <!-- file menu bar end-->
    <div width="100%" style="height: 100%;">
         <zssjsp:page id = "page3">
        <zssjsp:div  width="100%" height ="100%" apply = "com.project.handler.prjHandler","resource.js.src.js">
<%--    <zssjsp:window  id = "win"  height="100%" width="100%" > --%>
    <zssjsp:spreadsheet id = "ss" 
     vflex="1" hflex="1" maxVisibleRows="150" maxVisibleColumns="40"
     showToolbar="true" showSheetbar="true" showFormulabar="true" />

     </zssjsp:div>

    </zssjsp:page>
    </div>`
```

js code

```
newspreadsheet = function(){

    prjHandler.newbook();
}
```

javacode

```
public void doRefresh() throws Exception {
   Path path = new Path("//page3/ss");

    doAfterCompose(path.getComponent("//page3/ss"));

}

public void newbook() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("inside");
    doRefresh();
    System.out.println("inside");
    ss.setSrc("/root/Desktop/book/hellozss.xlsx");

}
```

i m getting an null pointer error in this line doAfterCompose(path.getComponent("//page3/ss"));

any help would be greatly appreciated

thank you !!

Comment: Acording to the [Path documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Guide/ZK_in_Depth/Component_Path_and_Accesibility/Access_UI_Component), the path needs to specify all `IdSpace` components on the way to the component you want to find. Could you try `\\page3\win\ss`?

Comment: Yes I have specified  all the id's

Comment: I have tried the win.. It's not working.. Added the win component and tried it.. I m getting the same error